# Does Loctite 270 wick?

Tags: thread, threadlocker

I have a bottle of Loctite 270, which looks like it's a green threadlocker.

According to [this post](http://henkeladhesivesna.com/blog/the-difference-between-red-blue-green-and-purple-threadlockers/) green Loctites can wick into the threads of pre-assembled components.

An example of this is [Loctite 290](https://www.techsil.co.uk/media/pdf/TDS/HEAN00004-tds.pdf):

> Because of its low viscosity and capillary action, the product wicks between engaged threads and eliminates the need to disassemble prior to application.

However, the Loctite 270 [technical data sheet](https://www.techsil.co.uk/media/pdf/TDS/HEAN00003-tds.pdf) boasts no such claim. I cannot see it listed in the Loctite brochure either (see [Page 10](http://dm.henkel-dam.com/is/content/henkel/threadlocker-user-guide%20(1)pdf)).

So, does it wick? If not, why is it green?

[image: Locite 270]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blurb I've seen says:

> Loctite 270 High Strength Studlock 10ml High strength for locking and
>   sealing of threaded fasteners and close-fitting parts after assembly.
>   Penetrates tightened threads, porous materials and cracks by capillary
>   action. Testing should be carried out prior to contact with styrene,
>   acrylic and polycarbonate based plastics to ensure compatibility.

The "after assembly" and "Penetrates tightened threads" parts clearly imply wicking. If you look at the data sheets of the green products none of them state they wick or penetrate threads, don't know why.

The blurb is a sales blurb I saw on several sites, example [here](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pipe-thread-sealants/0514521/).

Comment: They probably won’t put wicking on the data sheet as they can’t guarantee the performance ie how **far** it will wick...

Comment: Could you link to the blurb?

Comment: I edited to add @Zaid.